# Unknown column in 'field list' IN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE FUNCTION fnc_credit_custstatus
 RETURNS VARCHAR(6) DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
 DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
 IF CustCredit>=1000 THEN SET custstatus='VIP';
 ELSEIF CustCredit<1000 THEN SET custstatus='NONVIP';
 END IF;
 RETURN custstatus;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

I think I created FUNCTION has succeeded，but when I SELECT the function is Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'fnc_credit_custstatus' in 'field list'

```
 SELECT*, fnc_credit_custstatus AS custstatus
 FROM customer_salon
```

Comment: This is clearly not sql server, so I removed the tag. Please don't tag products not involved

Comment: did you forget to add parenthesis? fnc_credit_custstatus()

Comment: 'SELECT*, fnc_credit_custstatus(custstatus) 
FROM customer_salon'           Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'custstatus' in 'field list'

Comment: I tried to add parenthesis， but is still error

Comment: Just `... fnc_credit_custstatus() ...`... But where does `CustCredit` come from in the function's body?

Comment: `CustCredit` come from the table name：customer_salon

Comment: You do have to pass a parameter..and this doesn't syntax because you don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to pass a parameter..and this doesn't syntax because you don't define one.

```
drop function if exists f;

DELIMITER //
 CREATE FUNCTION f(custcredit int)
 RETURNS VARCHAR(6) DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
 DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
 IF CustCredit>=1000 THEN SET custstatus='VIP';
 ELSEIF CustCredit<1000 THEN SET custstatus='NONVIP';
 END IF;
 RETURN custstatus;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
 set @cr = 2000;
 select @cr,f(@cr);

+------+--------+
| @cr  | f(@cr) |
+------+--------+
| 2000 | VIP    |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

or in your case

SELECT *, f(custcredit) AS custstatus
 FROM customer_salon

Comment: My database has a table name:`customer_salon`  the `custcredit` parameter is in there.

Comment: YOU have to pass it to the function and the function has to have a parameter to accept it. see edit. and 'customer_salon the custcredit parameter' is just nonsense.

Comment: I need to list the output by including all the column fields in the `Customer_Salon` table as well as the `custstatus` of all the customers. how can I use the parameter from `Customer_Salon` to accept it？

Comment: Incorrect number of arguments for FUNCTION database.fnc_credit_custstatus; expected 0, got 1

Comment: `DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION fnc_credit_custstatus
RETURNS VARCHAR(6) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
IF CustCredit>=1000 THEN SET custstatus='VIP';
ELSEIF CustCredit<1000 THEN SET custstatus='NONVIP';
END IF;
RETURN custstatus;
END //
DELIMITER ;
SELECT *, fnc_credit_custstatus(custcredit) AS custstatus FROM customer_salon`

Comment: `DELIMITER //
 CREATE FUNCTION f(custcredit INT)
 RETURNS VARCHAR(6) DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
 DECLARE custstatus VARCHAR(6);
 IF CustCredit>=1000 THEN SET custstatus='VIP';
 ELSEIF CustCredit<1000 THEN SET custstatus='NONVIP';
 END IF;
 RETURN custstatus;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
 SELECT *, f(custcredit) AS custstatus 
 FROM customer_salon`Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER ;
 SELECT *, f(custcredit) AS custstatus 
 FROM customer_salon' at line 1

Comment: My code works fine see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fwJDV8khLci1vTKsNT5N9c/0 .